# Seem to have hit a dead wall with google trying to find total sales for every month for salespersons coding in php

Tags: php, sql

Task: Find total product quantity sold by every salesperson every month and make a report. I used an outer loop for salesperson and and inner loop having a SUM() query 12 times for every salesperson while storing the data in a multi dimentional array i.e., for every salesperson index, I intend to store 12 index values for the 12 month sales.

Problem: When I use the query in the inner loop, its not showing summing up product_quantity coloumn. When I use the query outside the loop for a specific id and month, the query sums up the sales for the month correctly. So, whey is the query not working in the inner loop. Is it because calling the query 12 times for every salesperson makes the process inefficient? 
Is there a better way to do it?

```
            while($salesperson=mysql_fetch_array($qry1))
        {
            $postData[$i]=$salesperson['name'];
            echo $postData[$i];
            echo "</br> ";
            $m=1;
          while($m<=3)
            {
                $qry2=mysql_query("Select SUM(addsales.product_quantity) AS Total from addsales where sid='".$salesperson['sid']."' AND month='".$m."'");
                echo $qry2;
                echo "</br>";
                $total=mysql_fetch_array($qry2);

                    if($total['Total']!=0)
                    {
                        $postData[$i][$m]=$total['Total'];
                        echo $postData[$i][$m];
                    }
                    else
                    {    $postData[$i][$m]=0;
                    echo $postData[$i][$m];}


                $m++;
                echo "</br>";
            }
            $size--;
            $i++;
        }
        echo "</br>";

        mysql_close($con);

        $i=1;

?>
```

Comment: Try `print_r($postData)` before `mysql_close($con)` and Show the result here..

Comment: Unrelated: you might want to use mysqli or PDO for your Database work.  mysql_query has pretty much been depreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From a database standpoint, the outer and inner looping is inefficient, since the same results can be achieved with far fewer database round-trips when you send a SQL query that is closer to what you actually want.

```
SELECT s.sid, s.name, 
(SELECT SUM(a1.product_quantity) FROM addsales a1 
 WHERE a1.sid = s.sid AND a1.month = '1'
) AS month1sold,
(SELECT SUM(a2.product_quantity) FROM addsales a2 
 WHERE a2.sid = s.sid AND a2.month = '2'
) AS month2sold,
(SELECT SUM(a3.product_quantity) FROM addsales a3 
 WHERE a3.sid = s.sid AND a3.month = '3'
) AS month3sold,
(SELECT SUM(a4.product_quantity) FROM addsales a4 
 WHERE a4.sid = s.sid AND a4.month = '4'
) AS month4sold,
(SELECT SUM(a5.product_quantity) FROM addsales a5 
 WHERE a5.sid = s.sid AND a5.month = '5'
) AS month5sold,
(SELECT SUM(a6.product_quantity) FROM addsales a6 
 WHERE a6.sid = s.sid AND a6.month = '6'
) AS month6sold,
(SELECT SUM(a7.product_quantity) FROM addsales a7 
 WHERE a7.sid = s.sid AND a7.month = '7'
) AS month7sold,
(SELECT SUM(a8.product_quantity) FROM addsales a8
 WHERE a8.sid = s.sid AND a8.month = '8'
) AS month8sold,
(SELECT SUM(a9.product_quantity) FROM addsales a9 
 WHERE a9.sid = s.sid AND a9.month = '9'
) AS month9sold,
(SELECT SUM(a10.product_quantity) FROM addsales a10 
 WHERE a10.sid = s.sid AND a10.month = '10'
) AS month10sold,
(SELECT SUM(a11.product_quantity) FROM addsales a11 
 WHERE a11.sid = s.sid AND a11.month = '11'
) AS month11sold,
(SELECT SUM(a12.product_quantity) FROM addsales a12 
 WHERE a12.sid = s.sid AND a12.month = '12'
) AS month12sold
FROM salesperson s
WHERE ....
```